# CookieCuller on Chrome

Tags: firefox-extensions, google-chrome-extensions

What's the equivalent of the Firefox add-on [CookieCuller](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/cookieculler/) for Google Chrome?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well you can use any of from these three extensions of Chrome:

**Features** of [Cookie Manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cookie-manager/kbnfbcpkiaganjpcanopcgeoehkleeck):

> Search through cookies
>    See all cookies
>    See cookies from sub domains
>    See cookies from current domain
>    Delete all cookies (note: some cookies recreate itself after deletion. So it may appear again in the list after deletion)
>    Delete cookies from a particular domain
>    Delete particular cookie
>    Add new cookie
>    Edit existing cookie

[Vanilla Cookie manager](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/vanilla-cookie-manager/gieohaicffldbmiilohhggbidhephnjj):

> With Vanilla you can select which cookies you want to keep on a whitelist. All unwanted cookies are deleted automatically (or manually if you prefer).

**Features** of [Edit This Cookie](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/edit-this-cookie/fngmhnnpilhplaeedifhccceomclgfbg?hl=en):

> Delete any cookie
>    Edit any cookie
>    Add a new cookie
>    Search a cookie
>    Protect a cookie (read-only)
>    Block cookies (cookie filter)
>    Export cookies in JSON, Netscape cookie file (perfect for wget and curl), Perl::LPW
>    Import cookies in JSON
>    Limit the maximum expiration date of any cookie

Comment: Edit This Cookie is the closest one to Cookie Culler, because of the ability to protect cookies.